# getCountryCodeForRegion('BV') returns calling code 0

Tags: android, phone-number

I have a country list with region code.. and I'm using `getCountryCodeForRegion` to get country calling code from region code.

e.g. `getCountryCodeForRegion('AU')` will return me `61`

but there are a few places that don't return the right country code - it's probably unknown and return zero instead:

e.g. Bouvet Island (BV), Antarctica (AQ), France, Metropolitan (FX), Kosovo (XK), Pitcairn (PN)..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this for country code:-

**First option**

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

**Second option**

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I have a whole list of countries that I need to convert from region code to country calling code. not my current device info.

Comment: So i think you have to create an static array of(Which is not return by getCountrycodeForRegion()) calling code with region code and access from that array.